# ruby on rails vue and html.slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, vue.js, slim-lang

I've started a ruby on rails application. In this one, we can found a search bar. Besides, the result is return by json format. And the view is updated by vue.

In a first time my controller

```
  def index
if params[:search].nil?
  render 'index'
else
  @organisations = Organisation.search(params[:search])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render json: {
        organisations: @organisations
      }, status: :ok
    end
  end
end
end
```

in a second times we check the result by a js file and here i integrate the vue

```
    if (Object.keys(event.detail[0].organisations)[0] != undefined){
  console.log ("results")
  console.log (" here we display the result json " + event.detail[0].organisations )
  document.querySelector('#results').classList.add("d-inline")

 var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
    data: {
      return{
        search_results: event.detail[0].organisations
      }
    }
  })
}else{
  console.log ("not results")
  document.querySelector('#no-result').classList.add("d-inline")
}
})
```

And the last file is the view where we indicate the results in vue. This view file is a .html.slim file.

```
     .container.w-100.text-center
    #app
      .all_details
        | {{ search_results }}
      ul.list-group.list-group-flush
        li.list-group-item v-for=("search_result in search_results")
          .row
            .col.mt-2
              | {{ search_result.id }}
            .col.mt-2
              | {{ search_result.name }}
            .col.mt-2
              button#ok.btn.btn-primary type="button"
```

So, when i search an element in a first time, the search bar is working properly and this one generate the json expected.The result display is clear and vue displayed the json and the different elements. But when i use a second time the search bar the result keep the same and is not updated. 
I've verify the `search_results: event.detail[0].organisations` is properly updated. But at the level on the view .html.slim file we didn't update the front page.

I've try to force the rerender of the view but without success.
To add an information, when i search different element (first time and second time we didn't have error in the server and the console of browser)

I would like know if something is wrong in my process, do you have already seen this issue ? or do you have an idea of the issue presented.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi all, To investigate, i've created quickly a new minimal application to illustrate my issue. So, here we have created a public link https://gitlab.com/arabakevin/rails-vue. In this link we can found a js file (https://gitlab.com/arabakevin/rails-vue/blob/master/app/javascript/packs/hello_vue.js) and a html.slim file (https://gitlab.com/arabakevin/rails-vue/blob/master/app/views/pages/welcome.html.slim). We have only two functions. The first one, change the data transmit at the VUE, the second one call the Vue function. And we have the same issue the data don't update, Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initialising `Vue` on each `ajax:success` events, which works only the first time because `Vue` is hooking into the page and therefore deletes the template, and its ID, which makes `Vue` throwing an error on the next calls stating that the template couldn't be found.

Instead, initialise `Vue` on page loading, and then use `Vue.set(object, key, value)` after the `ajax:success` in order to update the Vue's data `search_results` attribute.